# node js и выборка для чтения файла определенного расширения

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

как отсортировать и прочесть все фалы с расширением txt? Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

js:

```
 fs.readdir('one', (error,data)=>{
   data.forEach( file =>{
      
      if(path.extname(file) === 'txt'){ // понимаю что где-то тут косяк, а может и везде.
         fs.readFile(file,'utf8',(error , data)=>{
               switch(error,data) {
                  case error:
                     console.log(error);
                     break;
                  case data:
                     console.log('file:\n' , data);
               }
            });
      }
   })
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Кроме путей, нужно ещё учитывать, что расширение возвращается с точкой. Ну и использование switch у вас, кажется, не к месту. Оператор запятой там в скобках всегда будет возвращать второй операнд и вы всегда будет зачем-то сравнивать `data` c `error` и `data`. В общем, попробуйте так:

```js
fs.readdir('one', (error, data) => {
   data.forEach((file) => {
      if (path.extname(file) === '.txt') {
         fs.readFile(`one/${file}`, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
           if (error) console.error(error);
           else console.log('file:\n', data);
         });
      }
   });
});
```